# How to animate multiple R points per date in gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gganimate

I am working on animating the path of boats through the Pacific. I have a data set with ship ID, lat, lon, and dates. I have successfully been able to plot the points on a map and animate the points.

[image: Static Plot of Ship Paths]

Once I animate the points, it appears to skip some points in the animation. Look at the differences in path on the static plot above vs. the gif plot below.

[image: Gif Plot of Ship Paths]

Example of the ship data frame info. There are 5 unique ship ID. Some ship ID have multiple lat/lon entries for each datetime. My assumption is that the animation is only revealing one lat/lon for each ship per datetime and thus skipping duplicates hence the missing points in comparison to the static plot.

| ship | lat | lon | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 382914 | 49.22597 | -124.8141 | 2022-02-04 |
| 351364 | 54.16689 | -179.9273 | 2022-02-22 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Code for static plot image:

> ```
> map1 <- ggplot() +
>   geom_polygon(data=mapWorld, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
>                               color= "darkolivegreen", 
>                               fill="darkolivegreen") +
>    geom_path(data = BOATS, aes(x=lon, 
>                                y = lat,
>                                group = ship id,
>                                color = factor(ship)),
>                                size = 1.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
>   geom_point(data = BOATS, aes(lon, 
>                                lat,
>                                group = ship,
>                                color = factor(ship)), 
>                                alpha = 1, size = 2, shape = 21) +
>   
>  coord_sf(xlim=c(-180, -115), ylim=c(27,62), expand = FALSE) +
>  labs(x="Longitude", 
>       y="Latitude") +
>  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
>  guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 3, 
>                               byrow = TRUE, 
>                               override.aes = list(size=5))) +
>  mapTheme
>   
> map1
> ```

Code for animation:

```
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)

map1.animation =  map1 + 
                  transition_reveal(along = datetime) + 
                  ease_aes('linear') + 
                  enter_fade() + 
                  exit_fade() 
                
animate(map1.animation, fps = 30,
                        nframes = 360, 
                        width = 1071, 
                        height = 715)


anim_save("Boat Path.gif")
```

Comment: I am having the same problem with and number of distinct datasets. Did you find a way forward?